# How can I get the all value in one column using result()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Model:

```
function get_all() {
        $query = $this->db->get('loan');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_loan_name($code) {
        $this->db->where('loan_type_code',$code);
        $query = $this->db->get("loan_type");
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->data['loans'] = $this->loan_approval->get_all();
    $this->build_view("loan_approval/list.php");
}
```

In "LOAN TABLE" it have a "loan_type_code" column i want to get all the value in this column and match to 2nd function.
Example

```
Loan table                             Loan Type Table

ID     loan_type           ID     loan_type_code   loan_type_name

1         EDL              1           EDL          Education Loan

2         DF               2           DF            Damayan Fund
```

I need to match the "loan_type" in table "LOAN" to "loan_type_code" in "Loan Type" table.
Im thinking if of query like this "$this->controler->get_loan_name($this->data['loans']->loan_type);" but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing it at DB level using a JOIN?

```
$query = $this->db->select('loan.*, loan_type.loan_type_name')
                  ->from('loan')
                  ->join('loan_type','loan.loan_type = loan_type.loan_type_code')
                  ->get();
return $query->result();
```